# Matching variable to two columns joined (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

A previous variable from a query gave me a value $name. I need to find the user id associated with that name, however in my users table I have two fields, firstName and lastName.

I cannot explode $name as I have both cases of double names (e.g. John Eric Smith) and last names (e.g. Jan van der Worde), so my attempt was to find a way to match firstName + lastName with $name.

My attempt was this:

```
$drid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName)='$name'";
$rest = mysql_query($drid);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rest)) {
    $driver_id = $row[0];
}
```

Unfortunately, nothing comes out as a result for $driver_id (whereas $name returns a result).

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why don't you just query out the id with the previous query?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn - the previous query simply extracts the name from a longer string of text, so there is nothing in that one that would give an indication of the user ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
<?php
$drid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE '%".$name."%'";
$rest = mysql_query($drid);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rest)) {
    $driver_id = $row[0];
}
?>
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to produce any result either but I see how LIKE would be preferable as $name is a string (or rather, what remains of it). Good practice surely!

Comment: @WillWP Ofcourse, that's why I have written this query for your case.

Comment: I gladly upvoted :) but for some reason, even the above does not appear to be working. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: Sorry to hear. What actually you want to have output?

Comment: I narrowed down the problem - it appears to stem from the $name variable.
If, in the example you posted above, I replace it with the Name Surname of any user, the id appears correctly in any print. It's when I use the variable that it does not work.

In this case:

 $drid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) LIKE 'John Doe'";
 $rest = mysql_query($drid);
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rest)) {
  $driver_id = $row[0];
 } 

I would get driver_id=4;

If I leave it as $name (and i know it works as i am outputting that too, i get nothing.

Comment: Well I think we are getting closer somehow, can you try it this way? `$drid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName) LIKE '%$name%'";`

Comment: It still won't give any result - tried also to drop the % but that didn't work either. I really do appreciate your help!

Comment: ahhh, it should work. My pleasure. What actually you would have in `$name`? are they all strings like: `Muhammad Mohsin` or `Will WP`?

Comment: That's correct - all strings of common names and surnames like the ones I mentioned in the opening post.

Comment: Did you echo your query and die it? and have checked it pasting mysql? `echo $drid = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName) LIKE '%$name%'"; die;`

Comment: That did the trick - it showed me that there was a pesky blank space ahead of the actual name. I feel quite silly now! Thank you for all your help, massively appreciated!

Comment: ahhhhaann nice to hear this. :) I was worried for you. ;) Glad I helped you getting through this. :) you very welcome Will..

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a new fullname field or using a temp table rather than using the concat, for performance reasons.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29285246/3923450 should work though if you are looking for a temp solution

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I am only after a temp solution as this is a one-off to update fields in an "old" table - new records already come ready with all the information required.